# access forbidden while accessing php application from other machine

Tags: php, web, easyphp

I am using easyphp5.3.6.0 to run the php application.
I have saved the php application folder in www directory.
now when I try to access it by giving 127.0.0.1 IP, it is working fine but when I try to run it with my actual IP address I get an error

"Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. "

please assist me with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably behind a router. You need to forward the port in your router's config page(which I guess is 80 that is the default port).

You can enter [here](http://www.portforward.com) they have information about port forwarding.

I also don't think you meant phpMyAdmin, as far as I know it's a mySQL manager

Comment: I use easyPHP for local test too. I did what I told you of port forwarding and I was able to access from other computers outside and inside the LAN.

Comment: no I am not behind a router. I am in local network. I think this problem is because of some permissions given in the cofig file of the server.

Comment: if you are able to do it, connect your computer directly to the internet modem and try to access to it from another computer/tablet/phone/internet connected device.  I also recommend you to use noip if you have dynamic IP. Just do some research, I'm sure it's doable and it's a pretty well documented topic